# Rotation issue for iPad after lock mode

Tags: ipad

My app supports both modes. Its supporting rotation perfectly, but has only one minor issue.

When I use my app in portrait mode and than I lock the device than I rotate and unlocks it, it still remains in portrait mode. What can I do to avoid this.

In Landscape when I lock it and than unlocks it in portrait, it works fine.

Thanks

Comment: I also see weird behavior where rotation will work on a view, but sometime later it will stop working. It is not always after an orientation lock.